# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumolib'

Tags: import, environment-variables, python-import, pythonpath, sumo

I have added the following in .bashrc file:
export SUMO_HOME="/home/azlaan/sumo/:$PYTHONPATH"

But still it cannot find the sumolib module.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the tools dir to the python path, so something like

```
export SUMO_HOME=/home/azlaan/sumo
export PYTHONPATH="$SUMO_HOME/tools:$PYTHONPATH"
```

should do the trick.